# Are the ways or plugins to automatically minify CSS, Html and Javascript code in Vim?

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify, vim-plugin

**I would like to know if there's a way of automatically minify html, css or javascript files.**
So that each time I save the *"source file"* Vim automatically make the same changes to a minified version of the file *(or automatically creates or override a minified version)*. **Something like this:**

---

***Source:***

```js
// The -is- object is used to identify the browser.  Every browser edition
// identifies itself, but there is no standard way of doing it, and some of
// the identification is deceptive. This is because the authors of web
// browsers are liars. For example, Microsoft's IE browsers claim to be
// Mozilla 4. Netscape 6 claims to be version 5.

var is = {
    ie:      navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
    java:    navigator.javaEnabled(),
    ns:      navigator.appName == 'Netscape',
    ua:      navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    version: parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.substr(21)) ||
             parseFloat(navigator.appVersion),
    win:     navigator.platform == 'Win32'
}
is.mac = is.ua.indexOf('mac') >= 0;
if (is.ua.indexOf('opera') >= 0) {
    is.ie = is.ns = false;
    is.opera = true;
}
if (is.ua.indexOf('gecko') >= 0) {
    is.ie = is.ns = false;
    is.gecko = true;
}
```

***Minified Version:***

```js
var is={ie:navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer',java:navigator.javaEnabled(),ns:navigator.appName=='Netscape',ua:navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),version:parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.substr(21))||parseFloat(navigator.appVersion),win:navigator.platform=='Win32'}
is.mac=is.ua.indexOf('mac')>=0;if(is.ua.indexOf('opera')>=0){is.ie=is.ns=false;is.opera=true;}
if(is.ua.indexOf('gecko')>=0){is.ie=is.ns=false;is.gecko=true;}
```

Comment: lol. generally we like to see source code, but this is one case where i don't think it was actually necessary (most of us know what minified means). nevertheless... +1 for effort

Comment: Ha, i know is just that lat time I asked they though I wanted to "compress" the files into zip or gzip files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not VIM, but the http://code.google.com/p/minify/ Minify project live compresses them on the internet, so you don't have to worry about your source files becoming compressed beyond recognition accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a plugin called [vim-minify](https://github.com/Shadowsith/vim-minify) which works by using:**

> .. the API from javascript-minifier.com and cssminifier.com by Andrew Chilton.

---

***In JavaScript***

- `:MinifyJS` minifies your javascript code to filename.min.js
- `:UnMinifyJS` reformat to be human readable

***In CSS files***

- `:MinifyCSS` minifies your css code to filename.min.css
- `:UnMinifyCSS` reformat to be human readable

Answer (score -1):

Enter visual mode select whole file and press `SHIFT-J`.